# Java, Passing value to a constructor of class inplementing Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, callable

So, I have implemented the following simple class to parallelize the independent encryption processes:

```
public class SelectionEncryptor implements Callable<BigInteger> {

    private DamgardJurik dj;
    private byte c;
    private int s;

    public SelectionEncryptor(DamgardJurik dj, byte c, int s) {
        this.dj = dj;
        this.c = c;
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger call() throws Exception {

        dj.setS(s);

        BigInteger r = dj.encryption(BigInteger.valueOf(c));
        System.out.println("dj s: " + dj.s + ", given s: " + s + ", c: " + c); 

        return r;
    }

}
```

**s** is just a parameter of the cryptosystem we use, but it is an important one determining the depth of the encryption.

I initialize and run my threads as following:

```
int s = s_max;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(selectionBits.length);
ArrayList<Future<BigInteger>> list = new ArrayList<Future<BigInteger>>();

// selectionBits is just a byte array holding 1's and 0's
for (int i = 0; i < selectionBits.length; i++) {

    dj.setS(s);

    SelectionEncryptor se = new SelectionEncryptor(dj, selectionBits[i], s);
    System.out.println("submitted: " + selectionBits[i] + " with s " + s + ", dj s: " + dj.s);

    Future<BigInteger> result = executor.submit(se);
    list.add(result);

    s--;
}

// collecting results

for (Future<BigInteger> future : list) {
    try {
        BigInteger f = future.get();
        out.println(f);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

executor.shutdown();
```

The problem is, even if I send the correct **s** values to the SelectionEncryptor, it just uses different values for it. This is an example output of my program:

```
submitted: 1 with s 6, dj s: 6
submitted: 0 with s 5, dj s: 6
submitted: 1 with s 4, dj s: 5
submitted: 0 with s 3, dj s: 3
submitted: 1 with s 2, dj s: 2
submitted: 0 with s 1, dj s: 1
dj s: 4, given s: 1, c: 0
dj s: 2, given s: 2, c: 1
dj s: 2, given s: 3, c: 0
dj s: 2, given s: 4, c: 1
dj s: 2, given s: 6, c: 1
dj s: 2, given s: 5, c: 0
```

I have tried setting **s** only in my main function, only in the callable class and now I'm setting it in both of them just to be safe but none of them have worked yet.

What can be the source of this problem? Do those callable instances share the DamgardJurick object? What I'm missing?

Sorry about the long question, I couldn't find a way to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your threads share the same instance of `DamgardJurik`, and each thread sets its `s` to the value it got from the main thread. Use a separate instance of `DamgardJurik` for each thread.

Comment: I thought about that but I did not implement it because the creation of a `DamgardJurik` object is a costly operation. The problem seems to be solved after adding `synchronized` keyword to the encryption block but this time we cannot use the advantages of multithreading. So, I think I better find a faster way to create the `DamgardJurik` object and implement your solution.

Comment: Or keep it as it is, but don't make it take an s as an argument of its constructor, but as an argument of the methods which need it. Of course, without knowing the code of DamgardJurik, it's hard to give a solution.

Comment: Okay, I just created a copy function for DamgardJurik, which creates a new object without recalculating the necessary key parameters, instead it just copies them from the given object. It seems to be working since all threads have different instances of the DamgardJurik object.